# Connecting to two different databases and compare the table result using shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I have a task of copying the data from one database to another.I don't have privileges to create DB Link.So, I have achieved this task using COPY command in shell script. But now, I need to compare the count of records between the databases. I used to do this manually. But now,I want to automate this.

As per my knowledge, Sqlplus allows me to connect to one database at a time. But I want something like

```
sqlplus -s un/pwd@sid <<EOF
 SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'abc'  -- first database
 UNION ALL
 SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'abc';  -- second database
exit
EOF
```

Is it possible to omit sqlplus string and add it in the query?

Thanks,
Savitha

Comment: This won't tell you anything. How do you know which database the count comes from? Plus you need a DB link in order to do it. Better to connect to each database in turn, return the value to the shell script and compare there. Even better, yell until you get a database link ( if it doesn't break any security procedures ).

Comment: @Ben: Tried a lot to get a DB link but my effort went in vain. :( But good for me. Got to learn COPY command. :) Now, I should learn to return the value to shell script and compare the same. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: can you explain what you want to have? what to you want to compare and what to be parametrised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use sqlplus substitution variables to store the query results:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#sthref1114

These variables are global to a SQL*Plus instance, so they retain their values upon connecting to another database.

Example:

```
SQL> variable var1 number
SQL> variable var2 number
SQL> conn a/b@ccc
Connected.
SQL> begin
  2  select 1111 into :var1 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print var1

      VAR1
----------
      1111

SQL> conn a/b@ddd
Connected.
SQL> print var1

      VAR1
----------
      1111

SQL> begin
  2  select 2222 into :var2 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :var2

      VAR2
----------
      2222

SQL>
```

We can also see them like this:

```
SQL> print :var2 :var1

      VAR2
----------
      2222


      VAR1
----------
      1111

SQL>
```

And use them in PL/SQL:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2  v1 number := :var1;
  3  v2 number := :var2;
  4  begin
  5     dbms_output.put_line('The difference is: '||to_char((v2-v1)));
  6  end;
  7  /
The difference is: 1111

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: looks like this resolves my problem. I shall try and update on this. Thank You. :)

Comment: Also check exp_dp/imp_dp as @David Aldridge has mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

you can rush something like this:

A sql file, let's name it tmp.sql:

```
select count(*) from user_tables;
--SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE column1 = 'abc';
exit;
```

A sh file, let's name it tmp.sh:

```
echo pass1 | sqlplus -s user1@sid1 @tmp.sql
echo pass2 | sqlplus -s user2@sid2 @tmp.sql
```

`./tmp.sh` would output something like:

```
Enter password:

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1717

Enter password:

  COUNT(*)
----------
        68
```

(chmod +x tmp.sh)

These scripts can be improved, but this can be a start.

Answer (score 1):

The COPY command is deprecated in SQL*Plus, and has a lot of limitations.

Data pump would be a much more robust way of handling this situation.